# Vue form repeater with parent and child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some problems with Vue form repeater.
I'm trying to make repeater that have repeater in itself, I made an example with parent and child.
The problem is with push method with child, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the code example: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/rade-ilijev/pen/zYNvgqK)

```
<template>
<div id="app">

<div v-for="(parent, index) in form.parent" class="form-repeater">
  <div class="form">

   <p>Insert Parent</p>

          <input v-model="name" placeholder="Name">
          <input v-model="age" placeholder="age">

      <hr>

      <p>Children</p>

      <div v-for="(child, index) in form.parent.children" class="form-repeater">
              <input v-model="name" placeholder="Name">
              <input v-model="school" placeholder="school">
      </div>

      <button @click="addChild">Add children</button>
  </div>
</div>
      <button  @click="addParent">Add parent</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                parent: [{
                    child: []
                }],
            },
        };
    },

    methods: {
        addParent: function () {
            this.form.parent.push({
                name: '',
                age: '',
            });
        },

        addChildren: function (index) {
            this.form.parent[index].children.push({
                child: {
                    name: '',
                    school: '',
                }
            });
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

So as you can see on codepen, I can add parent but child is not working as expected, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure why you are using this design, but it looks confusing to me (I'm easily confused).  You might want to try creating a base form component, and then build your ancestry tree of parents, children, etc., passing props down and events up.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://codepen.io/andref94/pen/abpdxvN) out.

```
    methods: {
        addParent: function () {
            this.form.parent.push({
                name: '',
                age: '',
                children: []
            });
        },

        addChildren: function (indexp) {
          console.log(indexp);
          
            this.form.parent[indexp].children.push({
                child: {
                    name: '',
                    school: '',
                }
            });
          console.log(this.form.parent)
        },
    }
```

I made some changes to your code:

- Added a property children of type array to parent object
- Changed addChildren function. Now child element is pushed into the children array of the parent of index passed to addChildren function